# Keep on shifting to N from D

Tags: automatic-transmission

I have a habbit of shifting to N from D to save gas. Is this bad to my cars engine? I read the manual and it says there that its damaging the engine brake. I need your help please. I just got this car and worries that it might damage.

Comment: If the manual says don't do this why would you? The average transmission rebuilt is close to $2000. Do you think shifting into neutral is going to save 800 gallons of gas to make it worth the repair?

Comment: In most modern cars, switching to neutral is not saving you any gas. If you're coasting down a hill in D, the engine will stop using any gas at all, instead using the cars momentum to keep the engine turning. If you shift into N, the engine will have to use gas to keep the engine turning at idle speed.

Comment: Thank you, moose lucifer and mike. Actually, its not in down hill. For example im nearing at the stop light or there is a heavy traffic ahead. I Immediately switch it to N.

Comment: So, the manual says don't do it ... And you loose engine braking but increase the wear on the brakes so factor in the cost of replacing those as well. Also, how is it a habit if you only just got the car?

Comment: You may have heard that it saves gas from an older aquintance. Because in the older carburated engines, this is true. Carbs don't cut-off the fuel when the engine is in overrun mode like injection engines do. I do it all the time in my carburated car, although I have a *manual* transmission. It also reduces manifold vacuum which you'd get when braking on the engine, so you get less oil consumption by leakage through the valve guides. However, only the latter still holds true with injection engines, but it's a minor advantage.

Comment: It was a habit because of my prev car its manual

Comment: Thank you, bart. So it doesn't damage the engine if i do d-n-d?